# python sqlite сравнение и запись разницы в базу

Tags: python, json, sqlite3, сравнение

имею json ответ с сайта, хочу сравнивать даты ответов с записанными ранее в sqlite.

Ошибка в том, что если даты нет в базе, то она записывается в sqlite, при повторном запуске функции она так же добавляет дату в базу, хотя она уже там есть использовал и == И !=.результат такой же.

то делаю не так?

```
#функция получения дат с базы.
def sq(id):
    with sqlite3.connect('wb.db') as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        info = cur.execute(f"SELECT data FROM orders{id}").fetchall()
        for i in info:
            return (i[0])

def raznica(id,headd ):
    with open(f'today_orders27{id}.json') as file:
        read1 = json.load(file)
        a=sq(id)
        for i in read1:
            if i["date"] == a:
                print("пропуск")
                break
        else:
            print('добавление')
            with sqlite3.connect('wb.db') as con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                # table=cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data3(data INT,art INT,town                            TEXT,category TEXT,subject TEXT) ")
                info = cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO orders{id} (data,art,price,category,subject) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",
                                   (i["date"], i['nmId'], i['totalPrice'], i['category'], i['subject'],))
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверь типы данных в таблице и JSON'е.

В sqlite, [как известно](https://metanit.com/sql/sqlite/6.3.php), время можно хранить множеством способов.

Comment: в базу заношу дату с такого же jsona, и после сравниваю такие же даты,
2024-01-25T00:48:43 такой формат

Comment: дебажил? проверь конкретно, что возвращается

Comment: @lovkiy56 все форматы, образцы данных базы и json, нужно поместить в вопрос, нужны типы данных в базе, хотя бы принт выведи что сравниваешь

Comment: Принтую тип данных у обоих выводит <class 'str'>

Comment: значения то равны на глаз? что выводит база интересно

Comment: лично я чтобы не пудрить себе мозги при работе с временем всегда timestamp юзаю. никогда не промахивается

Comment: Да , конечно равны.
когда даты нет в базе цикл ее наполняет, пробегаюсь повторно , условие не отрабатывает, и записывает повторно эти же даты, хотя они есть в базе

Comment: @lovkiy56 Это ж не даты, это строки, покажи обе строки как выглядят

Comment: Всем доброго дня.

Вот часть кода json {'date': '2024-01-09T00:35:07', 'lastChangeDate': '2024-01-09T09:02:12',

вот дата с базы  2024-01-27T01:50:28
оба эти параметра с типом str